# Flowtype generic function with different parameters

Tags: flowtype

I'm struggling with flowtype declaration for a generic function with different pairs of parameters.

My goal is to have a function which return an object of certain union type depending on input parameters.
I'm having a big load of messages that i want to type (for this example i'm using only two)

```
type Message1 = {
  event: 'UI',
  type: 'receive',
  payload: boolean
}

type Message2 ={
  event: 'UI',
  type: 'send',
  payload: {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: string;
  }
}

type MessageFactory<T> = (type: $PropertyType<T, 'type'>, payload: $PropertyType<T, 'payload'>) => T;

export const factory: MessageFactory<Message1> = (type, payload) => {
    return {
      event: 'UI',
      type,
      payload
    }
}

factory('receive', true);
// factory('send', { foo: true, bar: "bar" });
```

when i change

```
MessageFactory<Message1>
```

to

```
MessageFactory<Message1 | Message2>
```

it will throw an error

```
Could not decide which case to select. Since case 1 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 2 [2] looks promising too. To fix add a type annotation to `payload` [3] or to `type` [4]
```

You can ty it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCBGKBeKBvAUFFBAG4QB2wAXFAOQCqAkrQDSFSiQ20BOEAxhACWZVuzBIQAGwD2SACY0ARjJlSIScvgC++fJ2hxEqCACZsBIqQrU6TMUQPd4FeQ6gTpcxXnZEAZqrKquqaANx+UEpIPDTwwDxC5CgRRLq6+uCGCMho2LA5JpgAPgXGaKYRmZBluRAAYkj8wDI8IAA8ACoAfPkAFE5QACQACjwykDygnVldLHQGtN3znrIKNKPjk9OznfO0q95LAJTYvZ1V-DLk8VD+TS1tNEZ1jc2tHS9FvTgDWSuSNbyU5YXoEACQfGAAFceORfEREcQyJRuPY2EjHP9IkRDgpIuk9Pd3m0+rwBMJRPMEtCIMcIgB6BnDACiAA9IM0WTxxjx8Ey7g8PmSXOQ3PNcHcghweLT5tFYlAAEQKpVQbT0vRAA)

any idea how to declare this function?

or is it stupid idea and i'm going to the wrong direction?

any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `GenericMessage` with type parameters for your desired properties (type and payload), then have your factory return a `GenericMessage`:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#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-IolujMRQTHSCGgwOhHgFMhtNkxTWzNijFJmWPzhWaXgXQEWtjneaRy7dgBjgHRUKgYgBCfxAA))

```
type GenericMessage<TYPE: string, PAYLOAD> = {
  event: 'UI',
  type: TYPE,
  payload: PAYLOAD
}

const factory = <T: string, P>(type: T, payload: P): GenericMessage<T, P> => {
    return {
      event: 'UI',
      type,
      payload
    }
}

const test1 = factory('receive', true);
const test2 = factory('send', { foo: true, bar: "bar" });

// Let's check the new type against Message1 and Message2:
type Message1 = {
  event: 'UI',
  type: 'receive',
  payload: boolean
}

type Message2 ={
  event: 'UI',
  type: 'send',
  payload: {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: string;
  }
}

// Type assertions
(test1: Message1);
(test2: Message2);
(test1: Message2); // Error!
```

If you want, you can create a `MessageFactory` type that returns a `GenericMessage<T, P>`. You can also create an `EVENT` type parameter if you need to control the `event` property on the object.

(You don't need to call it `GenericMessage`, I just called it that to make a distinction between your existing types and this new one)

Comment: Hi @James, thanks for answering.
It's not quite the solution i'm looking for, because if you skip testing type assertions, flow will not throw any error when you put incorrect pairs of parameters into this function.

I would rather get error without testing assertions

Comment: In that case you might find it helpful to write multiple type defs for the function. Check out the lib defs in flow (lib/dom.js) for getElementsByTagName to see an example of this. Once you have all the declarations, set the `factory` function to be the type of the function you declared with `declare function`. There's probably a better way to do this, but that should work. If you can't figure it out after trying, leave another comment.

Comment: Quick example: https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIEYAKAfQC54BnDGLVAcwEoKiBvAaxAE8LraGAvowBQoSLAQp02PIVIVUyALYAjEDGbw2nHvEWr1Q4cLB5q8JVwBiaMBQxcADiByJC8ALxby8KKi6MngB8WtrcFCQCFH4BIiZmGFQ0FBzhSfz0Ap5yAEQAFiAQEDg5Iqao5vopOgrKajBZXojEBCJAA

Comment: (If you do figure it out, you can answer your own question)